# Is it possible to know the individual scores of the components of a query?

Tags: solr, lucene

I have a boolean query consisting of an OR between two query components, both of which are of type TermQuery.

Once the result documents are retrieved, a final score is associated, which is derived by a combination of the scores returned by the two term queries that are part of the main query.

Is there a way to know what were the two individual scores that resulted in the final score?

Answer (score 1):

Check the [debugQuery=true](http://docs.lucidworks.com/display/solr/Common+Query+Parameters#CommonQueryParameters-The%7B%7Bdebug%7D%7DParameter) parameter to get the break up of the scores for each individual document and fields that match and contribute to the score.

Comment: Is this supported in Lucene too?

Comment: yup .... searcher api has an explain method for lucene. e.g. http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0-BETA/core/org/apache/lucene/search/IndexSearcher.html#explain%28org.apache.lucene.search.Query,%20int%29